# Convert string of hex into vector of bytes

Tags: strings, rust

I want to write a function that gets a string of hex numbers (two hex numbers represent a `u8` value) then returns a vector of `u8` values, e.g. the string `1f 0a d1` should be converted into `[31, 10, 209]`. The input string may contains non hex characters, then the function must be able to filter these characters, such as:

```
1f\x0ad1
1f \x0a\xD1
\x1F \x0a \xd1
\x1f    \x0A\xd1
...
```

All of them lead to the output `[31, 10, 209]`. My solution is that following:

```
fn parse_hex(hex_asm: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let hex_chars: Vec<char> = hex_asm.as_bytes().iter().filter_map(|b| {
        let ch = char::from(*b);
        if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') || ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f') || ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') {
            Some(ch)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }).collect();

    let mut index = 0usize;
    let (odd_chars, even_chars): (Vec<char>, Vec<char>) = hex_chars.into_iter().partition(|_| { 
        index = index + 1;
        index % 2 == 1
    });

    odd_chars.into_iter().zip(even_chars.into_iter()).map(|(c0, c1)| {
        fn hexchar2int(ch: char) -> u8 {
            if '0' <= ch && ch <= '9' {
                ch as u8 - '0' as u8
            } else {
                0xa + 
                if 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'f' {
                    ch as u8 - 'a' as u8
                } else if 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'F' {
                    ch as u8 - 'A' as u8
                } else {
                    unreachable!()
                }
            }
        }
        hexchar2int(c0) * 0x10 + hexchar2int(c1)            
    }).collect::<Vec<u8>>()
}
```

But it does make me happy. There are several problems that I may think of:

1. It needs to create two sub-vectors, one for odd-index element, one for even-index
2. Because of performance, I wrote the function `hexchar2int` (which is ugly) to convert two hex number into a `u8` value instead of using `u8::from_str_radix`

I wonder if there is a better method to do that.

Comment: *because of performance* — you benchmarked to see that this was a bottleneck?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I didn't, I just thought that `u8::from_str_radix` is overkill because in this case I need to create a string of two characters.

Answer (score 5):

1. Note that this code will **not** work on any non-ASCII strings. These are more and more common, especially considering the global community we are a part of (and don't forget emoji ).
2. Use `Vec<_>` to avoid redundantly specifying the inner type when collecting.
3. Use byte literals `b'x'` instead of casting characters to bytes.
4. You can match on ranges of characters. I find this aesthetically pleasing.
5. Don't collect an iterator into a `Vec` just to call `into_iter` on the `Vec`. Instead, use the original iterator with `partition`.
6. Don't convert from `u8` to `char` and back. You only need to make a single transformation.
7. There's no need to use the turbofish with the final `collect` since it's being returned and the type can be inferred.
8. There's no need to call `into_iter` for `zip`'s argument, it's implied because it takes an `IntoIterator`.
9. Instead of partitioning into vectors, just grab two values out of the iterator at a time. Using `fuse` allows calling `next` after it's already returned `None`.
10. Your code handles the check of a hex digit twice, leading to the `unreachable`. Instead, perform the conversion when performing the check.

```
fn parse_hex(hex_asm: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut hex_bytes = hex_asm.as_bytes().iter().filter_map(|b| {
        match b {
            b'0'...b'9' => Some(b - b'0'),
            b'a'...b'f' => Some(b - b'a' + 10),
            b'A'...b'F' => Some(b - b'A' + 10),
            _ => None,
        }
    }).fuse();

    let mut bytes = Vec::new();
    while let (Some(h), Some(l)) = (hex_bytes.next(), hex_bytes.next()) {
        bytes.push(h << 4 | l)
    }
    bytes
}
```